# Why first-party clients can't handle 'authorization_code' grant type on Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I am working in two apps: `accounts.domain.com` (Laravel app) and `dash.domain.com` (Not laravel, but php). I want `dash` users to login through `accounts` to use the app, so I figured I could use OAuth to achieve this.

I installed Laravel Passport and everything worked fine when getting an authorization code:

```
$query = http_build_query([
    'client_id' => $clientId,
    'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri,
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'scope' => '*',
    'state' => $state,
]);

return redirect('https://accounts.domain.com/oauth/authorize?'.$query);
```

But then I tried to get the access token:

```
$response = $http->post('https://accounts.domain.com/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id' => $clientId,
        'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri,
        'code' => $code,
    ],
]);
```

And I got this error:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "Client authentication failed",
    "message": "Client authentication failed"
}
```

So I googled the error, and I found that maybe there was an error with my credentials, so I check them, tried to recreate them, and nothing.

Finally I got to this file `vendor/laravel/passport/src/Bridge/ClientRepository.php` and I found something really interesting in the `handlesGrant` method that is used to verify a client:

```
protected function handlesGrant($record, $grantType)
{
    // ...

    switch ($grantType) {
        case 'authorization_code':
            return ! $record->firstParty();
        // ...
        default:
            return true;
    }
}
```

I changed this line

```
return ! $record->firstParty();
```

To this:

```
return $record->firstParty();
```

And everything worked. So, what I can see is that, using `'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'` is only valid for third party clients.

My question is: ¿Why can't first party clients use `'authorization_code'` as grant type? And if they can, ¿how can I implement this without changing Laravel Passport files?

Comment: By first party you mean resource owner? One requires credentials, the other does not.

Comment: I guess you're not wrong @adam, though Laravel Passport does allow you to implement your logic for what a firstParty client is.

I set my clients to be firstParty in order to turn off the approval screen, as I didn't really want that to appear when users log in from my own applications. 

This is completely independent of creating public & private app clients so i guess I find it strange also that the logic is so strict in this area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled across the same problem, don't know why this is the default behavior. You can easily extend the ClientRepository and rebind it to the service container:

1. Create a file app\Passport\ClientRepository.php and put the following content:

```
<?php

namespace App\Passport;

use Laravel\Passport\Bridge\ClientRepository as BaseClientRepository;

class ClientRepository extends BaseClientRepository
{
    /**
     * Determine if the given client can handle the given grant type.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Passport\Client  $record
     * @param  string  $grantType
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function handlesGrant($record, $grantType)
    {
        if (is_array($record->grant_types) && ! in_array($grantType, $record->grant_types)) {
            return false;
        }

        switch ($grantType) {
            case 'personal_access':
                return $record->personal_access_client && $record->confidential();
            case 'password':
                return $record->password_client;
            case 'client_credentials':
                return $record->confidential();
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }
}
```

2. Register your ClientRepository, to rebind it to the service container:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use App\Passport\ClientRepository;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    // Other code

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->bindClientRepository();
    }

    /**
     * Register the client repository.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function bindClientRepository()
    {
        $this->app->bind(\Laravel\Passport\Bridge\ClientRepository::class, ClientRepository::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try this approach.

Comment: Thanks for this, solved the issue for me.